# Javascript - 2d Array Splitting based on Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a 2D array having Name, email and Age of a person. Can i Split the array into multiple arrays grouped by the age of the person. Eg: If the input array have 5 values -

```
[Name1, name1@test.com, 21], [Name2, name2@test.com, 22], [Name3, name3@test.com, 22], [Name4, name4@test.com, 22], [Name5, name5@test.com, 21]
```

the output i want is to two arrays one with the names and emails for age 22 and the other for age 21.

What will be best way to do it in javascript?

Comment: Your array is not valid...........

Comment: I did not understand. What did you mean by that

Comment: one way i can tell is reduce + map

Comment: @ChrisLi - what do you mean by reduce + map?

Comment: `name1@test.com` is string .....thus should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: on second thought map isnt needed, use reduce to iterate the array and every iteration reduce on the new array to check if that age already exist

Comment: i was just showing it a user firendly representation and it did not mimic the code

Comment: Numerous ways to do this. Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. It is expected you show attempts to solve your own issue and people help you with **your code** when it's not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` to create an object with age as keys and values as arrays with corresponding name and email addresses as array items:

```js
let data = [['Name1', 'name1@test.com', 21], ['Name2', 'name2@test.com', 22], ['Name3', 'name3@test.com', 22], ['Name4', 'name4@test.com', 22], ['Name5', 'name5@test.com', 21]];

let result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  let [name, email, age] = c;
  a[age] = a[age] || [];
  a[age].push([name, email]);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```